# Wordpress Store Locator Plus Plugin - I want the search field and button in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

I have the Store Locator Plus plugin installed in my wordpress website. Please have a look on the following url
http://coolcooks.thewebsitestore.net/?page_id=193

Is it possible to have the search field in another page and I can enter a location and then click the submit button to redirect to the above mentioned page(http://coolcooks.thewebsitestore.net/?page_id=193) and process the search?

I hope someone can help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Widget Pack allows you to do that.
http://www.charlestonsw.com/product/slp4-widgets/

Post at the forums at http://www.charlestonsw.com/forums/ for a response time of less than a year!!   I'm on Stack Overflow fairly often but I don't look for people asking questions about products here.